# How to silent warning incompatible property type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiscrollview

I am using `RTSPagedView` from github in my project. Which gives me this warning

```
  Property type 'id<RTSPagedViewDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>' unherited from 'UIScrollView'
```

in

`@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <RTSPagedViewDelegate> delegate;`

in `RTSPagedView.h`

App is working fine with this warning. Anyone came across this before or knows the solution please help.

Link for this is [RTSPagedView](https://github.com/rplasman/RTSPagedView)

```
//  RTSPagedView.h
//  PagedView
//  http://github.com/rplasman/RTSPagedView

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol RTSPagedViewDelegate;

@interface RTSPagedView : UIScrollView

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <RTSPagedViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger currentPage;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger numberOfPages;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL continuous;

- (void)resizeBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (UIView *)dequeueReusableViewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag;
- (UIView *)viewForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)scrollToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)reloadData;
- (NSUInteger)indexForView:(UIView *)view;

@end

@protocol RTSPagedViewDelegate <UIScrollViewDelegate>

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPagesInPagedView:(RTSPagedView *)pagedView;
- (UIView *)pagedView:(RTSPagedView *)pagedView viewForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@optional

- (void)pagedView:(RTSPagedView *)pagedView didScrollToPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)pagedView:(RTSPagedView *)pagedView didRecycleView:(UIView *)view;
@end
```

Comment: Please add a link to the github project and also show where in your code this warning appears.

Comment: More code please. Provide the property statement and the declaration of <RTSPagedViewDelegate>.

Comment: @reno jones https://github.com/rplasman/RTSPagedView/blob/master/PagedView/RTSPagedView.h this is how it's given der.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue occurred because

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <RTSPagedViewDelegate> delegate;
```

In this delagate is poniting towards `UIScrollViewDelagate` because `RTSPagedView` is inherited from `UIScrollView`.

Modify the complete delegate name with any other name like

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <RTSPagedViewDelegate> rtspDelegate;
```

It will remove the warning.

Comment: although i got few other warnings but this issue is solved in correct way.... thanku for explaining :)

Comment: @SmritiYadav Welcome :) Yeah, other warnings are related to JSONKit.m Which is third party classes. Not related to this.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <UIScrollViewDelegate, RTSPagedViewDelegate> delegate;`

Works for me.

Comment: I like this solution better than accepted answer. In accepted answer at least one delegate method I need wasn't called as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* (I cannot be sure without more code) that you are haven't declared your delegate class as conforming to the `RTSPagedViewDelegate` protocol.

try this:

YourClass.h:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate, RTSPagedViewDelegate>

...

@end
```

And now when you do:

```
rtsPageView.delegate = self;
```

The warning should be gone.

This could be complete rubbish, in which case I'll delete it.